# How to start creating a php script, that will be installed on many servers?

Tags: php, web-applications

I was wondering how to start coding a script using php, and that script will be used on many websites.
so should I start first by creating the database ? and then start creating php files that will process data from the database ?
and should I start thinking of an install wizard for this script at first, or later when I finish the project I'll create one ?
I'm really confused on how to start a project, can you please give me some advice ?

and thanks everyone :D

Comment: When you are referring to install wizard, are you talking about a php script that automatically creates a database and tables and populates them....

Answer (score 1):

> should I start first by creating the database?

If you are going to use a database in your PHP script, then yes, you should install a database first. MySQL is a good start.

> and then start creating php files that will process data from the database?

I would start on one server first, and create one PHP file called index.php that will do a database query. Then work your way to multiple PHP files from there.

> and should I start thinking of an install wizard for this script at first, or later when I finish the project I'll create one.

Installing PHP files is 90% of the times as simple as just copying them onto your new server. I wouldn't worry about an install wizard just yet.

---

Another general tip because you are a beginner: install [WAMPServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), it is a webserver/PHP server/MySQL Server in one that runs on your local computer. This is great for developing because you can just put your PHP files in `C:\WAMP`, edit them and directly see the result in your browser through `http://localhost/`. Then when you are happy you can upload to the server, or multiple servers. (Just by copying).

Answer (score 0):

Most php software does not have, or need for that matter, what you would call an install wizzard.

I would suggest you to develop whichever way feels most natural to you.

Some people find it easier to start with the database design, while others prefer to write some code first and then expand the db schema further. There really is no right way to do it.

Starting a PHP project can be as easy as creating a text file and pumping out lines of code, however if you plan on creating a sizeable project, I would suggest a fully featured IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was afraid of starting with a wrong way.

Comment: If you found an answer useful, please upvote it by clicking the upward pointing icon to the left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Decide what dependencies your script has.

Decide which minimum version of PHP the script will be compatible with.

Work out a script which queries the users setup to detect whether these conditions are met or not. (eg does it rely on the mysql extension to be installed).

Detail how to meet each of the dependencies in case they are missing.

Explain which is the minimum version number supported, if your script detects it is below that version number.

Test it on your target Operating Systems.

Run a script which creates a database, test whether that was created. Provide detailed instructions on how to do this manually, and how to provide the correct privileges.

If necessary give them a config file which permits them to enter key information such as doc_root etc.

Conform to common wisdom such as short_tags = off else override these settings. Imagine the user is on shared hosting and is running on safe_mode = on.

Try and follow your own instructions and re-install it on your localhost, then on a live server - ideally on a variety of OSs too.